# Download & Save Zoom Recording in directory by PHP

Tags: php, copy, zooming, recording

Some time ago this code was working fine. I was able to download a file into a directory by using a `copy` command but it stopped working. It is no longer downloading a file. It always creates a `0-byte` file.

The code I'm using:

```
$video_url = 'https://api.zoom.us/rec/download/tJN4d7v5_Ts3HtzD4QSDVqJwW9XoJvms0nUbq_cPnRzhUCMAN1alZrVAN-AD8vw4clXzSccEqqZtfZw_';
$local_file = getcwd() ."/tmp/tmp_file.mp4";
copy($video_url, $local_file);
```

I have tried various ways to download and save but nothing helps.

Comment: Please post errors if comes, so we can understand it better what is wrong with copy function.

Answer (score 3):

Your $video_url returns 302 http response. Try this

```
$src = 'https://api.zoom.us/rec/download/tJN4d7v5_Ts3HtzD4QSDVqJwW9XoJvms0nUbq_cPnRzhUCMAN1alZrVAN-AD8vw4clXzSccEqqZtfZw_';
$fileName = 'tmp_file.mp4';
$dest = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
$ch = curl_init($src);
curl_exec($ch);
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $downloadLink = $info['redirect_url'];
}
curl_close($ch);

if($downloadLink) {
    copy($downloadLink, $dest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the access token in order to download the video recordings

here is the line you will update to pass the access token

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,download_URL?access_token)`

As only host is allowed to record and download the meetings. By passing access token you will allow to download the meetings for every user.

Access token is the token you would be generating from JWT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).